# xPages Dojo Grid Events Not Working

Tags: xpages, dojox.grid.datagrid, xpages-extlib

I am attempting to double click on a dojo grid to open a document. During this exercise I have found that I cannot execute any events from the dojo grid. Even if I try to execute a relatively simple event such as navigating to a page on the dojo grid events it fails to run at all.

Is there anything that I am missing?
Is there anyway to troubleshoot this?

Thanks,

[edit]
8.5.2

[edit2]

```
    <xe:this.service>
        <xe:viewItemFileService contentType="application/json"
            defaultColumns="true" var="entry" viewName="RFCID">
        </xe:viewItemFileService>
    </xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>

<xp:br></xp:br>
<xe:djxDataGrid id="djxDataGrid1" storeComponentId="restService1"
    escapeHTMLInData="false" loadingMessage="Loading Data">


    <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn1" field="rfcid"
        label="RFC ID" width="30" editable="false">
    </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
    <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn2"
        label="Request Title" field="requesttitle" width="200">
    </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
    <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn3" label="Initiator"
        field="initiator" width="100">
    </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
    <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn4" label="Waiting On"
        field="waitingon" width="100">
    </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
    <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn5" label="Status"
        field="rfcstatus" width="150">
    </xe:djxDataGridColumn>





    <xp:eventHandler event="onRowDblClick" refreshMode="complete"
        immediate="true" submit="true">



        <xe:this.action>
            <xp:openPage name="/Home.xsp" target="newDocument"></xp:openPage>
        </xe:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xe:djxDataGrid>

<xp:br></xp:br>

</xp:view>
```

Comment: Please post your code... your description is too generic to surmise what the problem could be.

Comment: Is this your own implementation of the Dojo Grid or the Extension Library Dojo Data Grid control? The latter's onRowDblClick event was working when I wrote that chapter of the book. Please confirm Extension Libarry or Dojo.

Comment: Extension Library. But it seems that none of the events on the grid are working. Even if I try to implement an on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Extension Library Dojo Data Grid events are client-side, not server-side. That's because it is a Dojo control and the Dojo controls are client-side. See the examples in the demo database or the book for how to get a handle on the current row.